# How to remove the author name on wordpress blog posts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to remove the author name from wordpress blog posts . Also I dont want to delete the author name becoz I use different author names from admin side.

Comment: which wordpress theme are you using as twenty thirteen, twenty twelve?

Answer (score 1):

WP v4.1.2
Edit content-single.php:
Appearance->Editor->content-single.php

```
<div class="entry-meta">
      <?php // twentyeleven_posted_on(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-meta -->
```

Comment the middle line "twentyeleven_posted_on();" like above
Title line on post saying: Published By AUTHOR on DATE will not be displayed

OR (less recommended as it effects a wider scale)
*functions.php*

COMMENTED LINE get_the_author()

```
function twentyeleven_posted_on() {
printf( __( '<span class="sep">Posted on </span><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s" pubdate>%4$s</time></a><span class="by-author"> <span class="sep"> by </span> <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%5$s" title="%6$s" rel="author">%7$s</a></span></span>', 'twentyeleven' ),
    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
       esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'twentyeleven' ), get_the_author() ) )/*,
       get_the_author()*/
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the `single.php` file of your current theme through your ftp client or from Dashboard -->Appearance -->Editor
2. Delete this code : 
   `<span class="meta_author"><?php the_author(); ?></span>`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can comment/delete the line where author name is printed.

```
<span class="meta_author"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
```

Comment: Hi Pranita, it works for blog post page, but my home page shows the author name. Do you know how to remove it ?

Comment: You can hide author name on home page by using css. .entry-author-link,
.entry-permalink,
.entry-date,
.entry-meta {
 display: none;
}   This hides all the meta data related like author name, post date etc. Paste the code in style.css.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the author names from posts and search results on a site built with [The7](https://the7.io/) theme by adding this custom CSS:

```
a.author.vcard {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The other answers here that relate to the PHP code of WP are true, but alternatively this can also be done by modifying the CSS code of the site.

Under the main stylesheet file (style.css), you can add this definition:

```
.blog-title-body SPAN {
    display:none !important;
}
```

This specifically will hide both the author name AND the category name under the header of the post page (the post name).

If you want to remove only the category name, for example, you can put in the following definition:

```
.blog-title-body SPAN.cat-links {
    display:none !important;
}
```

**NOTE:
be sure to always make a backup copy of every built-in file on WP site that you modify!!
It is also highly recommended to make an entire site backup periodically, with and without relation to modifications and changes.**